# How to make an "apprequest" with c# Facebook SDK?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-app-requests

I would like to make an apprequest from my application using the c# facebook sdk.

After some investigation I found some examples that are using the app access token which has the following format : access_token = YOUR_APP_ID|YOU_APP_SECRET

Now I have tried the following using the appAccessToken:

```
string appAccessToken = String.Format("{0}|{1}",Constants.FacebookAppId,Constants.FacebookAppSecret);           

        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(appAccessToken);

        fb.PostCompleted += (o, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Error != null)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(args.Error.Message));
                return;
            }


        };

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = "Test: Action is required";
        parameters.data = "Custom Data Here";


        fb.PostTaskAsync(String.Format("{0}/apprequests", Constants.FacebookAppId), parameters);
```

But it doesn't work... Is it possible to make an apprequest using the c# Facebook skd?
I hope anybody can help me.

Have a nice day!
With best regards, Matthias

Comment: "It doesn't work" - Error from fb api or something else?

Comment: I get the following error in a messageBox : (GraphMethodException - #100) Unsupported post request

Answer (score 0):

To get access token of App.
Just use this link and you will get it

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

Please check this out : http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/tutorial.

To get user access token

Add this to App.xaml.cs

```
    internal static string AccessToken = String.Empty;
    internal static string FacebookId = String.Empty;
    public static bool IsAuthenticated = false;
    public static FacebookSessionClient FacebookSessionClient = new FacebookSessionClient(Constants.FacebookAppId);
```

Create a method to get Access token

```
private async Task Authenticate()
        {
            try
            {
                _session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream");
                App.AccessToken = _session.AccessToken;
                App.FacebookId = _session.FacebookId; 
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                var messageBox = new OneButtonCustomMessageBox
                {
                    TbMessageTitle = { Text = "Facebook Login Error" },
                    TbMessageContent = {Text = e.Message}
                };
                messageBox.Show();
            }
        }
```

After you have Access Token you will use a method like this to call GraphAPI from FB to get user information

```
 private async void LoadUserInfo()
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);

            fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message));
                    return;
                }

                var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(async () =>
                {    
                    var profilePictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type={1}&access_token={2}", App.FacebookId, "normal", App.AccessToken);                    

                    this.ImgAvatar.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(profilePictureUrl));
                    this.TxtName.Text = String.Format("{0}", (string)result["name"]);                    


                });
            };

            await fb.GetTaskAsync("me");
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Your sample is how to get an USER AcessToken via the Login-Flow, butI nedd the APP AccessToken

Comment: Hi, I just updated my answer, you can easily get the app access token via the link in the answer :) or find out how to use graph api to get app access token here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/